# Missing something for code; ArrayList pattern with Add() and Remove() methods

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm working with this online book assignment and I passed the testing phase but not the assignment. It's requesting that I use the add() and remove() methods to remove a number from a list and add another number to replace what I took out. So for instance, the original list is `101 200 103` and I have to remove `200` and add `100` and `102` to make this order: `100 101 102 103`. I was able to code to for that scenario, but now it looks like I need to make this add() and remove() method more universal. I'll show what I mean.

**Directions**

> Modify the existing ArrayLists's contents, by erasing 200, then
>   inserting 100 and 102 in the shown locations. Use ArrayList's remove()
>   and add() only. Sample output of below program:
>
> 100 101 102 103

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListADT {

   public static void printArray(ArrayList<Integer> numsList, int numOfElem) {
      int i = 0;

      for (i = 0; i < numOfElem; ++i) {
         System.out.print(numsList.get(i));
         System.out.print(" ");
      }

      System.out.println("");
   }

   public static void main (String [] args) {
      ArrayList<Integer> numsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      int numOfElem = 4;

      numsList.add(new Integer(101));
      numsList.add(new Integer(200));
      numsList.add(new Integer(103));

// CODE ABOVE THIS COMMENT CANNOT BE MODIFIED

      numsList.remove(new Integer(200));
      numsList.add(0, new Integer(100));
      numsList.add(2, new Integer(102));

// CODE BELOW THIS COMMENT CANNOT BE MODIFIED

      printArray(numsList, numOfElem);

      return;
   }
}
```

The code I have allows for the initial request (`101 200 103 -> 100 101 102 103`) to be completed.

> Checking with numsList originally 101 200 103
>
> Your output:  `100 101 102 103`

However, it another test appears and fails.

> Checking with numsList originally 6 7 8 9
>
> Expected output: `100 6 102 8 9`
>
> Your output: `100 6 102 7 8`

In both these tests, the original first number (`n0`) takes the place of the original second number (`n1`) and `n1` is removed from the list. Furthermore `100` and `102` appear that they need to be kept in the code as they are also tested with `6 7 8 9`. I also experimented trying `numsList.remove(new Integer(101));` and `numsList.remove(1, new Integer(101));` to the code to see what I'd get as an error. The error statement follows:

> Checking with numsList originally 6 7 8 9
>
> Expected output: `100 6 102 8 9`
>
> Your output: `100 101 102 6 7`

How do I make this code fully work? I feel like it's something so simple but I'm blind to see it.

Comment: I don't understand the tests. Your question is defined using specific numbers, if you change those numbers to 6-9 how can you apply the same question?

Comment: @Zarwan Most of the tests/practices are like this, where you are asked for one set of variables and it tests for another. I suppose it to see if the code can be applicable for other similar scenarios.

Comment: In your situation the "tests" being applied are not tests at all, I'd say they're completely unrelated to the task you were given: `Modify the existing ArrayLists's contents, by erasing 200, then inserting 100 and 102 in the shown locations. Use ArrayList's remove() and add() only.` An algorithm shouldn't be defined based on a single input and output.

Comment: `numsList.remove(1);`? It may look like they want the item in index 1 of the original list removed, the way I read the expected output. It seems straightforward, doesn’t it?

Comment: @Zarwan It's to test my knowledge and understanding of the chapter I'm learning but from what I understand from the tests. It basically acts like this: `original list: a b c...` -> `100 a 102 c...` The dot-dot-dot being extra variables not affected.

Comment: @OleV.V. That was it! I knew I was making it harder that it really was but at least I knew it was something with `n1` (index of 1). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we look at the expected output from the two tests: From the list `101 200 103` they expect 200 to be removed. From `6 7 8 9` they expect that 7 be removed. In both cases, it’s the item at index 1 (since indices are 0-based). So instead of

```
  numsList.remove(new Integer(200));
```

do

```
  numsList.remove(1);
```